# If only CI fails, what kind of trouble could there be for django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations

#### Overview

The configuration file for github-actions is as follows.

```
name: Django CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 1
      matrix:
        python-version: [ 3.11 ]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
          cache: pip

      - name: Set up and run tests
        env:
          DB_ENGINE: django.db.backends.mysql
          DB_NAME: portfolio_db
          DB_USER: root
          DB_PASSWORD: root
        run: |
          # https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#mysql
          sudo systemctl start mysql
          mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;"
          python3 --version
          python3 -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
          python manage.py makemigrations register
          python manage.py migrate
          python manage.py makemigrations vietnam_research gmarker shopping linebot warehouse
          python manage.py migrate
          mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD -e "USE portfolio_db; SHOW TABLES;"
          export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="$(base64 <<< "$RANDOM|TeStiNg|$RANDOM" | tr -d '\n')"
          python manage.py test
```

#### detail

This CI will fail at this time.
The migration seems to be working fine and it seems failing in the testing process.
https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/7517515573/job/20463770730

[image]

I'm also curious about the difference in the number of tests detected...

It works fine on the VPS server, so I don't know why it's failing in CI. If anyone knows please help me